# Beginner problems in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been stuck for about an hour and after googling and doing research I could't get my code to run. It shows not a single error and when I press run it just opens debug and does nothing. I am using eclipse. I am trying to create a list of 10 objects and to give them random numbers.

```
class test {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int a [] = new int[9];{
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                a[i] = a[(int)(Math.random()*70+15)];
            for (int elem : a){
                System.out.println(elem);
            };              
}}}
```

Comment: indenting, and not having random curly-brace blocks make code easier to read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are actually launching the application, it should fail with an exception at the following line:

```
                a[i] = a[(int)(Math.random()*70+15)];
```

Here, `a[]` consists of nine elements, so its highest index is 8. However, `Math.random()*70+15` is guaranteed to generate numbers that are greater than 8.

Comment: Yeah I was about to say... If he didn't get an error there, then he rolled rather low

Comment: Sorry I just tried to give one elemnt value and it didnt work I changed it.

Comment: @Cruncher: He couldn't have. The `+15` makes this fail every single time.

Comment: @NPE: yeah I realised after I posed

Comment: it might be worthwhile to edit the failing code excript to reflect the op's updated code.  just so that nobody is confused.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any Java, but I would say :

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
a[2] = a[(int)(Math.random()*70+15)];
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*70+15);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the Random number generator instead. I would also suggest using better names than `i` or a for your programs.

```
import java.util.Random;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random object = new Random ();//declare for your object
        int a;    //declare your integer type (I would suggest   
                  // changing that to be more descriptive)
        for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++) 
        {
            a = object.nextInt(100); // change 100 to however large   
                                     // parameter you want
            System.out.println(a + " ");
        }

    }              
}
```

Comment: For java7 and above it is best to use `ThreadLocalRandom`. Take a look e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/3519000)